# How to get a count array of objects by month with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need an array of 12 integers that count for every month of the year how many elements of the following array belong, the month is included in the date attribute which can be handled as a string.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Order 1",
        "date": "2020-06-15T18:05:43.040468",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Order 2",
        "date": "2020-06-15T18:05:55.397698",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Order 3",
        "date": "2020-05-15T18:06:15.853506",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Order 4",
        "date": "2020-03-15T18:06:44.421666",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Order 5",
        "date": "2020-05-15T18:06:44.421666",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Order 6",
        "date": "2020-01-15T18:07:03.856468",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Order 7",
        "date": "2020-02-15T20:09:25.164826",
        "type": "Affectation",
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Order 8",
        "date": "2020-03-15T20:09:25.164826",
        "type": "Affectation",
    }
]
```

The result would be like that:

[1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Please check the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Share your code, so people can help you to improve it. It's not a place where someone does your homework instead of you.

Comment: It's pretty trivial.  Did you at least try something?: `const mos = Array(12).fill(0); data.date.map(({date})=>+date.slice(6,8)).forEach(m=>mos[m]++)`

Comment: ^ In slightly friendlier terms: please include your attempt at solving the problem, not just a problem to solve. We are happy to help you find where your attempt has gone wrong, but not so happy to make the full solution for you.

Comment: @user120242 It will stop working after 7980 years!)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME it's not even fully working yet, 0 index and all.  But point still stands

Comment: Thanks @user120242 and BrianThompson, the problem is more difficult than what I presented, I just made it easier for you so you can try solving it. Any way the answers bellow helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use forEach. And index each month by using getMonth which returns an integer of what month it is. Then increment the respective month in the array.

```
// Create array of 12 items init'd at 0
// increment the count of each month
const monthCountArr = new Array(12).fill(0); 
data.forEach(({ date }) => monthCountArr[new Date(date).getMonth()] += 1);

console.log(monthCountArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I decided to give it a try and here is the code.

```js
const orderData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Order 1',
        date: '2020-06-15T18:05:43.040468',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Order 2',
        date: '2020-06-15T18:05:55.397698',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Order 3',
        date: '2020-05-15T18:06:15.853506',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Order 4',
        date: '2020-03-15T18:06:44.421666',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Order 5',
        date: '2020-05-15T18:06:44.421666',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Order 6',
        date: '2020-01-15T18:07:03.856468',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Order 7',
        date: '2020-02-15T20:09:25.164826',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Order 8',
        date: '2020-03-15T20:09:25.164826',
        type: 'Affectation',
    },
];

// This function takes a string and creates a date object from the string and return the month. 
const findMonth = (datestring) => {
    let date = new Date(datestring);
    return date.getMonth();
};

const makeDateArray = (orders) => {
    let monthFreq = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // you can use Array.fill() but for clarity
    // now you loop over each object in the data array
    for (const order of orders) {
        const month = parseInt(findMonth(order.date));
        // Months are from 0-11 in JS so it matches directly with array index
        monthFreq[month] = monthFreq[month] + 1;
    }
    return monthFreq;
};

console.log(makeDateArray(orderData));
```

Result -

[image: result]

In the future, atleast give it a try and ask question on where you are stuck instead of just asking the question from Zero! GL!